# Latency on pselect caused by other user space processes

Tags: linux, performance, io, debugging, scheduling

I have the following **pre-condition** on Linux:

- I'm using a process to read serial data using pselect on a serial device `/dev/ttySX`.
- Data comes in at a stable frequency of 400 Hz.
- To optimize latency of that process I used some measures:

  - The reading thread is pinned to a core (using affinity) and no tasks are allowed to run on that core. This is done via cgroups/cpuset.
  - The reading thread has an RT prio of 49 (just below the IRQ processes) with the SCHED_FIFO policy.
  - The IRQ corresponding to `/dev/ttyS4` is pinned to that same core. Also the IRQ process runs on that core. This was done to further reduce latency.
- Fully loading the system with `stress --cpu XX --io XX` does not affect the latency of the readings, and they come in nicely at 400 Hz

---

The **problem** I experience:

- There is another offending user space process which uses a lot of resources. When this one runs, it can cause huge latency spikes on my serial read thread. It can be 100 ms or more, even though serial data from the hardware arrives at 2.5 ms.
- I don't know too much about that other offending user space process, except that it is using the regular 'nice' scheduler and it spawns a lot of threads.

---

My **question**:

- Any ideas / approaches how I can possibly debug this? Maybe using ftrace, but I am not quite sure where to start.
- Any ideas what could cause such a behavior?

---

At this point, I am happy for any hints/ideas, thanks!